# cookie NOT stored in browser

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, cross-domain

and there my cors policy config

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "https://client-boggy.vercel.app",
    path: "/",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
  })
);
```

but NOT Working  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afpep.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you shared, it looks like `httpOnly` option is set to true, [which prevents client side JavaScript from accessing the cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie).

Comment: this's code in express file to setHeader

```
  res.setHeader(
        "Set-Cookie",
        cookie.serialize("at", token, {
          httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : false,
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : false,
          path: "/",
          sameSite: "none",
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week})
        })
      )
```

Comment: @AbdelfatahAshour based on that code and the `httpOnly` property, if you're running in production, the cookie won't be accessible or visible by client side javascript. That answers you question, doesn't it?

Comment: yes,i am don't try access it with javascript app in production so i set httpOnly true , issue is cookie not available at all paths and cookie has property path: "/",
EX : /:category/:brand here i can see cookie in browser storage APi but at /home can't see it!

Comment: Hmm. Can you share a link to the 'browser storage API' you are referring to?

Comment: i mean tab Storage in google chrome browser,